# Custom powerpoint viewer for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, powerpoint, quicklook

I want to write a simple powerpoint presentation viewer, that would allow the user to view different slides from different files at the same time, for example:

**File 1 : Slide 5**
User taps "next".
**File 2 : Slide 9**

The ordering of the slides is pre-set by the user, my question is, would this be possible using the normal QuickLook framework Apple provides? If not, are there good presentation frameworks out ? I haven't stumbled upon any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can also display it using a UIWebView : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html